# insert standard text into mysql with form data insert?

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting some form data into a sql database, but i want to insert an account type label aswell which is not part of the form data.

So basically the form data gets inserted into the database fine, but i also have a column in my database called 'account_type' which i want to insert the word 'member' into as standard.

Can i do this because i have tried by adding this to the code but it doesn't insert the 'member' into the account type.

Code i have tried adding:

```
<? $result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_registrations SET account_type=Member"); ?>
```

Rest of insert code for form data:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // other php code here


    $_SESSION['display_name'] = $_POST['display_name'];
    $_SESSION['password'] =  $_POST['password'];

    ?>

    <?php ob_start(); ?>
    <?php
    session_start();
    // GET ACCOUNT INFORMATION FROM FORM AND ASSIGN VARIABLES
    $first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $date_of_birth = $_SESSION['date_of_birth'];
    $contact_number = $_SESSION['contact_number'];
    $display_name = $_SESSION['display_name'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    ?>
    <?php
    /*
    // ECHO ACCOUNT INFORMATION
    echo "<strong> Account Information: </strong>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo First Name: ";
    echo "<br />";
    echo $first_name;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Last Name: ";
    echo "<br />";
    echo $last_name;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Email: ";
    echo "<br />";
    echo $email;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Password: ";
    echo "<br />";
    echo $password;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "date_of_birth: ";
    echo "<br />";
    echo $date_of_birth;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Contact_number: ";
    echo "<br />";
    echo $contact_number;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "display_name: ";
    echo "<br />";
    echo $display_name;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    */
    ?>

    <?php
    ////// SEND TO DATABASE


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Database Constants
    define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASS", "");
    define("DB_NAME", "playtime");

    // 1. Create a database connection
    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }

    // 2. Select a database to use
    $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $query="INSERT INTO ptb_registrations (ID,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    display_name,
    date_of_birth,
    contact_number,
    password

     )
    VALUES('NULL',
    '".$first_name."',
    '".$last_name."',
    '".$email."',
    '".$display_name."',
    '".$date_of_birth."',
    '".$contact_number."',
    '".$password."'
    )";
    mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
    ?>
    <?
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_registrations SET account_type=Member");
    ?>
    <?php
    function confirm_query($result_set) {
                    if (!$result_set) {
                        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                    }
            }
    function get_user_id() {
        global $connection;
        global $email;
        $query = "SELECT *
                    FROM ptb_registrations
                    WHERE email = \"$email\"
                    ";
            $user_id_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($user_id_set);
            return $user_id_set;
            }
    ?>
    <?php
    $user_id_set = get_user_id();
    while ($user_id = mysql_fetch_array($user_id_set)) {
        $cookie1 = "{$user_id["id"]}";
        setcookie("ptb_registrations", $cookie1, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */

    }
    ?>

    <?php include ('includes/send_email/reg_email.php'); ?>

    <? ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: `Member` must be single-quoted as a string in the `UPDATE` statment `SET account_type = 'Member'`

Comment: Beyond this, your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. At a _minimum_ you must call `mhysql_real_escape_string()` on each of those `$_POST` query inputs, and the `$_SESSION` inputs to protect against second order SQL. injection

Comment: Note also, that without a `WHERE` clause on the `UPDATE` statement, it will modify _all rows_.

Answer (score 0):

Why not insert it at the same time as the registration?

```
$query="INSERT INTO ptb_registrations (ID,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    display_name,
    date_of_birth,
    contact_number,
    password,
    account_type
     )
    VALUES('NULL',
    '{$first_name}',
    '{$last_name}',
    '{$email}',
    '{$display_name}',
    '{$date_of_birth}',
    '{$contact_number}',
    '{$password}',
    'Member'
    )";
```

The following

```
<? $result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_registrations SET account_type='Member'"); ?>
```

will result in making ALL account_type's equal to 'Member' when you dont have a `where` clause.

To answer you problem, it is most likely due to the fact you do not have single quotes around member in your update command, see my code.